# Showing native 'child' entries for an entry in the CP

Tags: entries

Is anyone aware of an #eecms extension which adds a list of 'child entries' to a parents edit screen in the control panel? I'm sure I've seen an extension that does this in the past but I can't locate it. :/

Edit: I should add, this is for EE1.x but I would happily reverse migrate a EE2.x extension (if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want Introvert by @iain
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/introvert

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's the one - EE 2.x only but I'll contact Iain and see if he minds me back porting it for personal use. :)